# find route distance & time taken to travel between two points using leaflet

Tags: leaflet, cloudmade

I am able to find route between two points using cloud mode & leaflet using this.
[CloudMade Routing with Leaflet: route is not displayed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49608/cloudmade-routing-with-leaflet-route-is-not-displayed/54744#54744)
But I also want to find distance & time taken to travel from first point to last point.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at an example of route : http://routes.cloudmade.com/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/api/0.3/47.25976,9.58423,47.26117,9.59882/car/shortest.js

You can adapt the function given on the post [CloudMade Routing with Leaflet: route is not displayed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49608/cloudmade-routing-with-leaflet-route-is-not-displayed/54744#54744) to retrieve response.route_summary : there you will find total_distance and total_time.